# How to write a good generator-chaining function

Tags: python, generator

I have the following functions:

```
def read_data(file_location):
    for line in open(file_location):
        # pre-process the line  
        yield line

def transform_1(data):
    for line in data:
        # change line in some way
        yield line

def transform_2(data):
    for line in data:
        # change line in some other way
        yield line

def process_file(file_location):
    # Some description
    #
    # returns:
    #     generator
    data = read_data(file_location)
    data = transform_1(data)
    data = transform_2(data)
    return data
```

What I am trying to do is reading lines from a file, transforming each line with a number of functions, and then doing something with the resulting lines. I don't want to read all lines at once as the file is quite big.

My question is if I am doing this the right way. The code executes correctly, but the program execution in my head feels convoluted, to the point where I have no idea whether I will be able handle this code in a month or so.

So what I want to know is: Is there some kind of programming pattern that shows how to properly chain generators into each other?

Comment: first: simplify this: `read_data(file_location)` => `open(file_location)` will do exactly the same.

Comment: This is a simplified version of my actual code. It does much more in real life.

Comment: @ArneRecknagel This is basically what Python's `map` was made for (this applies to Python 3, where `map` is lazy). Transform functions would then apply to _elements_ of the data set, not to the complete set, as this is what your generator yields. For a non-builtin tool you could take a look at [`RxPY`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY).

Comment: I'm not a fan of having everything as `data = ...`.  Give things descriptive names.  Dave Beazley has a [presentation on using generators like this](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/).  The main example starts on slide 34

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each line is transformed in the same way, you could apply your transform functions to each line and use a generator to iterate over all lines, personally I find this more readable.

```
def transform_1(line):
    return line.replace(' ','') # example of transformation

def transform_2(line):
    return line.strip('#')

def process_file(file_location):
    with open(file_location) as in_f:
        for line in in_f:
            yield transform_2(transform_1(line))
```

Depending on what the transforms do, they could possibly be combined into a single function, but it's hard to know without more context.

Comment: The transformers are separated for readability. So you'd advice to have the outmost function `yield` instead of returning a generator?

Comment: Well `yield` does create a generator so I'm not sure I understand the distinction you make. Of course you could trivially use a generator expression instead like `return (transform_2(transform_1(line)) for line in in_f)`

Comment: Hard-coding the transformations inside the data generator is not a good idea. This prevents flexibility in what transformations you want to apply. However applying transformations to _items_ (not to a complete set) is a good idea and this can be neatly realized with `map`: `map(transform_2, map(transform_1, process_file(...)))`.

Comment: @a_guest It's hard to know without more context, of course you could parse the transform functions as arguments to `process_file`. I'm not convinced using `map()` is more pythonic, but maybe it's all too subjective

Comment: I think I like this approach. @a_guest what do you mean with hard-coding? Do you mean merging all functions into one?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel I mean that when you already apply transformations within the function that is supposed to yield the data, then it is not straightforward to just get the untransformed data (if you ever need it). It's better to have things separated: One function yields the data, others transform it. Like that you can choose which transformations you want to apply, and things are also separately maintainable. Plus it feels more natural i.m.o.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is well done.  I'm not sure why the code feels convoluted to you.  The key is that each function is doing one thing only is a plus.  Obviously the function names should reflect the kinds of transformations that are being made.  Code like this is very testable and maintainable.  When you need to make a change to the pipeline six months from now, you might be surprised how easy it is to find the part than needs adjusting an make the change.

I would suggest modifying your read_data generator as follows:

```
def read_data(file_location):
    with open(file_location) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Comment: I think because the object is reassigned several times but the assignment at the top still influences its behaviour. I think I feel that after i make `data = x(data)` I do not need to know what `data` was before that call, only what `x()` does.

Comment: I typically change the name of data each time to reflect how it has changed, especially since it may go through type changes, such that it might be a string, but the next generator in the pipeline may be producing tuples.